# several times a day my pages come in written lines, clearing the cache helps, what goes wrong

Tags: magento2, admin, template, cache, page

several times a day my pages come in written lines, clearing the cache helps, what goes wrong
magento 2.2.5

[image]

Comment: any error displaying in console ?

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue with Magento 2.2.5 and by applying below patch in vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php it got fixed.

https://github.com/mrIntegrator/magento2/commit/879383ddc0d4a0998ec9b20356044fdf5484725b

Follow below link on Github to learn more about this issue

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6942#issuecomment-373594479